# powerpoint xml file show like html on web browser

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, schema, powerpoint

after powerpoint 2010, there is no way to save into html.

I understand that MS support xml instead of html.

but, when I open xml, it does not look like powerpoint at all.

xml looks just like bunch of data list...

is there any way to look like html(original powerpoint look) from xml on web browser?

I research about it a little, like [xsd(schema)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936285(v=office.12).aspx) for xml...

but, it's not work well.
the result looks just like xml data list page.

// **** c# code **** //

```
protected void xml2html5(){
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

    settings.Schemas.Add(null, "C:\\www\\xml2html5\\assets\\Schema.xsd");
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new XmlTextReader("C:\\www\\xml2html5\\assets\\test1.xml"), settings)){
        Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        while (reader.Read()){
            Response.Write(reader.ReadOuterXml());
        }
        Response.End();
    }        
}
public void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs ee){
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("********* Error Message222 : " + ee.Message + " **********");
}
```

how can I show powerpoint xml file as original html on web browser?